# sql select where column is a count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with users, and I have another table with activity, the user who had the activity is logged in a column. how could I make a query so that I can select each user with the count of activities they have.

I really can't think of how to do it nor search for something like this on the web.

so for example

**User table**

```
id | name
1  |  john 
2  |  karen
```

**Activity table**

```
id | user_id
1  |  1
2  |  1
3  |  2
```

**Results**

```
name | Count
john | 2
karen| 1
```

Comment: May be you should give a try

Comment: but how can i try if i had no idea?

Comment: You obviously made no attempt... but now you have been gifted the answer with no lesson learned

Comment: Google is your friend. Hint : `Join` + `Count` Aggregate

Comment: i did try this, and how can you say i havent learned a thing? now i know that i can select a count and display it as a column

Comment: @pato.llaguno - If you try something to achieve the result, then please do post it along with the question. It is highly encouraged here

Comment: @Fireblade thanks Fireblade, ill take that advice in the future, im sorry if i made it look as i did no effort

Comment: @pato.llaguno - Thats great!.. Its time to choose one as answer. May be Left Outer join answers are more meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `LEFT JOIN` and `COUNT` aggregate

```
SELECT name, COUNT(a.user_id) count
  FROM [User] u LEFT JOIN Activity a
    ON u.id = a.user_id
 GROUP BY u.id, u.name
```

Output:

```
|  name | count |
|-------|-------|
|  john |     2 |
| karen |     1 |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8fc28/3)** demo

Recommended reading:

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, count(a.Id) as ActivityCount
  from [user] u
 inner join activity a on u.Us = a.UserId
 group by name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  u.id as user_id, -- name is not necessary unique
  max(u.name) as name,
  count(a.Id) as [count]
from
[User] u
left join Activity a -- left join becuase some users can have no activities
on u.Id = a.user_id
group by u.id
```

Answer (score 1):

very simple to do.  You can combine the two tables by using a join.  To have the count (ie the total count) added, there is a function you can use which is conveniently called "Count".  So all together, it would look something like this-

```
select u.id, u.name, count(*) as ct
from tblUser u
left join tblActivity a on u.id = a.id
group by u.id, u.name
order by ct desc
```